# Is there an error in the SQL query. It is not stuffing the results with the following SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am still getting separated rows even though there are many instances where the branches should be grouped with a single string output containing the branch list of emails.

```
SELECT 
    upv1.PropertyVal AS [Branch],
    STUFF((SELECT '; ' + CAST(upv2.propertyval AS VARCHAR(36))
           FROM upa.UserProfileValue upv2 
           WHERE upv1.RecordID = upv2.RecordID
             AND upv2.PropertyID = 9
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') [Emails]
FROM 
    upa.UserProfileValue upv1
WHERE
    upv1.PropertyID = 11
    AND upv1.PropertyVal <> 'Missing Branch'
GROUP BY
    upv1.PropertyVal, upv1.RecordID 
ORDER BY 
    upv1.PropertyVal
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `upv1.RecordID` from `group by` clause

```
SELECT 
upv1.PropertyVal as [Branch],
STUFF((select '; ' + cast(upv2.propertyval as varchar(36))
    from upa.UserProfileValue upv2 
    where upv1.RecordID = upv2.RecordID
    and upv2.PropertyID = 9
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') [Emails]

FROM upa.UserProfileValue upv1
    where upv1.PropertyID = 11
    and upv1.PropertyVal <> 'Missing Branch'
group by upv1.PropertyVal 
order by upv1.PropertyVal
```

Comment: I have updated the SQL query as suggested, and now I get an error. 

`SELECT 
 upv1.PropertyVal AS [Branch],
 STUFF((SELECT '; ' + CAST(upv2.propertyval AS VARCHAR(MAX))
  FROM upa.UserProfileValue upv2 
  WHERE upv1.RecordID = upv2.RecordID
    AND upv2.PropertyID = 9
  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [Emails]

FROM upa.UserProfileValue upv1
 
WHERE upv1.PropertyID = 11
  AND upv1.PropertyVal <> 'Missing Branch'


GROUP BY upv1.PropertyVal
ORDER BY upv1.PropertyVal`

Comment: I get the error `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 Column 'upa.UserProfileValue.RecordID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`